# Canvas.DrawCircle inverting circle when radius is < 1

Tags: java, android

I'm having some trouble with the following code, it appears to drawn the circle inverted (inside out).  If I change the radius parameter from 0.25f to 1.0f then it does draw a circle.

```
    /* this changes the scale to 0 to 1 */
    float scale = (float) getWidth();
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.scale(scale, scale);

    Paint basicpaint= new Paint();
    basicpaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    basicpaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    handScrewPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    canvas.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.25f, basicpaint);
```

Can someone set me straight?

UPDATE:  I am using SDK version 14, if I switch to version 4 this code works.  Before you ask, no I can't switch version as there are API's in 14 that I need for my app.

Comment: what are the values of `scale` at `canvas.scale(scale, scale);`?

Comment: scale will be 300 pixels.  I'm using the Canvas.scale() method so in the rest of my drawing code I can use the values between 0 and 1 instead of the actual canvas size because it may change.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using the scale code

Try with the following code, seems to work fine though the 0.25f circle is too small to see with human eye

```
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint basicpaint= new Paint();
        basicpaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        basicpaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        basicpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawCircle(100f, 100f, 0.25f, basicpaint);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried the above code and it works fine. Interesting thing is if I make `minSdkVersion` to 14 it draws something but the results are not right. Even though I am running on ICS device, changing `minSdkVersion` to 13 works fine. I tried disabling hardware acceleration (as @John Willis said) with `minSdkVersion` set to 14 it works. Here is the summary in short:

- If you set `minSdkVersion` to 14 then HW acceleration is on by default.
- If you set `minSdkVersion` to 13 then HW acceleration is off by default.

soln 1: switch off hardware either manually or my `minSdkVersion`
soln 2: scale urself by calculating scale factor like

```
float scale = (float) getWidth();
mscale.setScale(scale);
.....
canvas.drawCircle(mscale.getX(0.5f), mscale.getY(0.5f),
            mscale.getUniScaled(0.25f), basicpaint);
```

Class for scale

```
    class MyScale {
    float scaleX;
    float scaleY;
    float uniformScale;

    public void setScale(float scale) {
        scaleX = scale;
        scaleY = scale;
        uniformScale = scale;
    }

    private float getX(float x) {
        return x * scaleX;
    }

    private float getY(float y) {
        return y * scaleY;
    }

    private float getUniScaled(float value) {
        return value * uniformScale;
    }
}
```

Here is the image for api level 10.

[image: Circle]

So the only problem I can think of is with `getWidth`. Check your layout or code which is setting this width. It could be that for some reason this with is too low. For your code to work, the width cannot be less than 4 (preferable 5 as there is floating point calculation). As `drawCircle` cannot draw smaller than [1 pixel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle%28float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

**Edit 1**

Running on api level 14 works fine.

[image: Circle with api level 14]

Comment: You are correct this code does work if you are using SDK version 4 but not with 14.

Comment: Try turning off hardware acceleration for that layer.